# Find multiple string matches using Java regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to use regex to find a match for a string between `Si` and `(P)` or `Si` and `(I)`.

Below is what I wrote. Why isn't it working and how do I fix it?

```
String Channel = "Si0/4(I) Si0/6( Si0/8K  Si0/5(P)";

if (Channel.length() > 0) {
    String pattern1 = "Si";
    String pattern2 = "(P)";
    String pattern3 = "(I)";

    String P1 = Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)[" + Pattern.quote(pattern2) + "|" + Pattern.quote(pattern3) + "]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(P1);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(Channel);

    while(m.find()){
        if (m.group(1)!= null)
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
        else if (m.group(2)!= null)
        {   
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }

}
```

Expected output

```
0/4
0/5
```

Actual output

```
0/4
0/6
0/8K  Si0/5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookbehind and lookahead in your regex. And also you need to add space inside the character class, so that it won't this `0/8K` string .

```
(?<=Si)[^\\( ]*(?=\\((?:P|I)\\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mR2iF0/1)

```
String str="Si0/4(I) Si0/6( Si0/8K Si0/5(P)";
String regex="(?<=Si)[^\\( ]*(?=\\([PI]\\))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher =pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
0/4
0/5
```

Comment: `(?:P|I)` = `[IP]` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your regex.It is currently

```
Si(.*?)[(P)|(I)]
```

Whereas it should be

```
Si(.*?)\(I\)|Si(.*?)\(P\)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oO8zI4/8

Comment: You ought to escape the parentheses: `Si(.*?)\([IP]\)`

Comment: @Tomalak it was der in the regex link.forgot here.thanx

Comment: Still not correct, because you have two groups in your expression but actually you only want one.

Answer (score -1):

[] means "any of these character", so it evaluates every letter in the block as if they were separated with OR.

If the result you're searching is always: number/number
You can use:

Si(\d+\/\d+)(?:\(P\)|\(I\))